# Cassandra C# driver: Linq table queries returning data from first keyspace after changing keyspace on session

Tags: c#, linq, cassandra

I'm using CassandraCSharpDriver 3.4.0.1

My C# application needs to create new keyspaces and be able to switch between them on the fly. Everything works fine except for direct table Linq Where queries, ex.:

```
_table.Where(...).Execute(),
```

which always return data from first keyspace, even if I recreate the table objects with a new session (or use ChangeKeyspace on the same session).

Executing insert statement on session using ExecuteAsync (created from table objects) works fine and data is correctly inserted in new keyspace.

```
var insert = _table.Insert(new Values()
                {
                    ...
                });

_session.ExecuteAsync(insert);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define [one class per table in your mappings](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.4/features/components/linq/#configuring-mappings). If you have 2 different tables in different keyspaces, you should use 2 different classes.

Also, you should avoid switching between keyspaces on your `Session` to query different tables, you can specify the keyspace of the table in the mappings definition:

```
MappingConfiguration.Global.Define(
   new Map<User>()
      .TableName("users")
      .KeyspaceName("ks1")
      // ...
)

MappingConfiguration.Global.Define(
   new Map<AnotherClass>()
      .TableName("table2")
      .KeyspaceName("ks2")
      // ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It won't be possible in my case to create different classes per keyspace, since they can be created dynamically. One workaround I found is to build and use CQL select statements directly on the session object, and copy results from RowSet to my table class.